Several pages in Inkscape view?
I have imported a PDF document into my Inkscape 1.2.2 document. To my surprise, in addition to the content of the PDF, it has created an A4 "page" to the right hand side of my current page:

I can control its background colour eg along with the one of my left hand side page using the Document properties dialog, but apparently not its size... or presence?
Exporting to PDF the whole document, it is a 2-paged document now.

This is for Inkscape 1.3, I think it's mostly the same as 1.2.  If not I would suggest you update to the latest stable version: Currently 1.3.2 as off today 29/04/2024.
Anyway, to delete a page . . .
Select the Pages Tool (at the bottom of the toolbar) 
Select the page by clicking on it.
Hit Delete or use the Delete Page button in the control bar along the top

If you want to change its size, select the page, then use the corner handles to resize the page

or type its size directly in the control bar along the top.


Thanks, I was surprised not to see anything in Doc properties or along with the page selector... and hadn't seen this new Tool.

@Joce - yeah, that's because this is fairly new functionality, since the introduction of multipage documents in Inkscape 1.2.  The document properties dialog didn't have enough functionality to control multiple pages, so they added a new tool for it.

It's great that multipage documents will be now supported, actually I was more pleased to discover that than distressed by my little practical problem!
